# Pass Messages Between Backbone.js Views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'm currently working on a bug in my company's backbone application in which a task in progress in one view should disable behavior in another view. The behavior we're looking for is when the task begins and the user navigates to the second view, the behavior is already disabled, but because the view hasn't been rendered yet the event to disable the behavior isn't triggering.

Is there a way around this without parameterizing the view?

Current code is as follows:

**In settings.js:**

```
handleUpdateClick: function(evt) {
    // ...
    EventDispatcher.trigger('updatingStateChanged');
    // ...
}
```

**In dashboard.js:**

```
initialize: function(options) {
    EventDispatcher.on("updatingStateChanged", this.handleUpdatingStateChanged);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Without code we only can guess.

Comment: @hindmost I posted a little bit of (I'm guessing largely unhelpful) code, I'm under a pretty strict NDA so there's not a whole lot I can do unfortunately.

Comment: he problems with a stateless event model is if you "miss" the event, you have no way to check what state you are in. using a global state model gets over that

Answer (score 0):

In general, what many applications do is have a global "application state" model, where you store your current state, and can share data/events between components.

Answer (score 0):

Another Option would be to have a global Application Controller, maybe based on `Backbone.Router` which functions as a singleton for event and message passing - have seen this quite often in large projects.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the current answers, in one of my Backbone apps I created a central Hub to listen for events. So it works like this

```
//This is outside your view code
var HUB = {};
_.extend(HUB, Backbone.Events);
```

In your view you listen for events on the Hub:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    HUB.on('state:change', this.handleUpdatingStateChanged, this);        
        // ...
}
```

Then in your settings.js you can trigger events against the Hub like so:

```
handleUpdateClick: function(evt) {
    // ...
    HUB.trigger('state:change');
    // ...
}
```

I think this approach could solve your problem. It's quite simple to implement too. One important gotcha is that you must remember to stop listening and undelegate events from the hub when you close a view - typically you'd just add a `HUB.off(null, null, this);` to your existing zombie view cleanup/close approach.